# Тестирование RestTemplate junit5 - "ResponseEntity.getBody() because is null"

Tags: java, mockito, resttemplate

Есть рабочий метод который дергает рест. При его тестировании junit5 получаю ошибку

```
public Country getCountry() {
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.set(SYSTEM_CODE, "code");
   ResponseEntity<Country> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
            properties.getUrl(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity(headers),
            Country.class);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
   }

//testing
Country country = new Country();
country.setId(1);

ResponseEntity<CountryPage> mockEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(country, HttpStatus.OK);

Mockito.when(mockEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(country);

Mockito.when(clientRestTemplate.exchange(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Country>>any()))
            .thenReturn(mockEntity);

//do
some.getCountry();
```

результат:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because "responseEntity" is null
```

Какова причина, почему он `null` когда определен.
Находил похожие варианты но ситуация не исправилась.

UP: ошибка вылетает на уровне `return responseEntity.getBody();`.

Comment: Из этого кода нельзя сказать почему. Не видно как создается `some`, в особенности, как ему подкладываются `properties` и `clientRestTemplate`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval могу сказать если дернуть апиху в котором находится этот метод то все отрабатывает

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь. Но в тесте-то это все подменяется. И не работает, потому что неправильно подменяется.